# Dojo dijit/focus does not make keyboard appear in Firefox and Edge on Surface

Tags: javascript, firefox, dojo, keyboard, microsoft-edge

I want to popup the touch keyboard when the input field get the focus through a java scripts call. Below is my sample code and it works fine with chrome browser but Firefox and Edge it doesn't.

http://jsfiddle.net/BUX4b/75

```html
<input id="foo" type="text"><br><br>
<button id="newActButton">New Act Button</button>
```

```js
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dijit/focus", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(on, dom, focusUtil) {
        var newActButton = dom.byId("newActButton");
        on(newActButton, "click", function(){   
            focusUtil.focus(dom.byId("foo"));        
        });
    });
```

Comment: what do you mean popup keyboard ? can you give the expected result because this example gives same result on both ffoex and ie + chrome

Comment: When we click on the button input field should get the focus and touch keyboard should appear automatically, Then user should be able to type on the input field directly.

Comment: Wroks as you expect , ay be problem in your browsers !!!

Comment: Did you check with surface pro ?

Comment: no sorry, just for desktop